# Bootstrap ignore style modifications

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a simple webpage using Twitter Bootstrap.

At the sidebar I have 3 buttons. Each of this buttons calls a function to show one div and hide the others.

The HTML code is something like:

```
<div>
   <div class="row" id="general" style="display:none">
   Text1
   </div>
   <div class="row" id="medication" style="display:none">
   Text2
   </div>
   <div class="row" id="diet" style="display:none">
   Text3
   </div>
</div>
```

And this is one of JS functions that hide/show the DIVs:

```
 function showGeneral(){
        document.getElementById('general').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('medication').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('diet').style.display = 'none';
      }
```

I update the code with @ChaoticNadirs answer but still does not work.
[Here is my code at Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/4fNKysU8b2)

The problem is that the function works properly but once it finish all DIVs became hidden again (as default).

I feel the problem could be in any transition due to Twitter Bootstrap framework.

Does anyone how to solve this?

Comment: At a first glance nothing in your code stands out. However, without seeing what else is going on in your file and what other functions are called it's hard to say why you are having issues. 
you could try to assign bootstraps classes (show and hidden) rather than setting the display values: http://getbootstrap.com/css/ search for "Showing and hiding content"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bootstrap provides a `.hidden` class. You can use this rather than the display style to hide and show elements.

Check this bootply for an example: http://www.bootply.com/uY7kHe3Nw7

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" id="show-general">Show General</button>

<div>
   <div class="row hidden" id="general">
     Text1
   </div>
   <div class="row" id="medication">
     Text2
   </div>
   <div class="row" id="diet">
     Text3
   </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#show-general").on('click', showGeneral);

function showGeneral(){
        $('#general').removeClass('hidden');
        $('#medication').addClass('hidden');
        $('#diet').addClass('hidden');
      }
```

**EDIT:**

In your new example you are firing the event on a `<div>` click inside an `<a>` tag. You can do something like this to prevent the default action:

JS:

```
$('#showGeneral').on('click', showGeneral);

function showGeneral(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#general').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#medication').addClass('hidden');
    $('#diet').addClass('hidden');
    $('#workout').addClass('hidden');
}
```

Here's a new bootply: http://www.bootply.com/3RkAbPX6d0

Comment: This is a elegant way to do what I was looking for, unfortunately despite to use the `.hidden` class I still does not work...
I made an example of my code at Bootply and update the question.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using the "visibility" attribute... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility you can read more about it here.

Usually I apply a class to an element I would like to hide. This way it prevents using inline styles. If you don't care about inline styling you could also use jQuery's show(),hide(), or toogle() methods.

I do not think that the issue is with Bootstrap.